# Posting a form using apache cxf

Tags: java, cxf

I am trying to post a form which contains file as well as normal text data.
I am using Apache CXF for this. Below is the code

```
WebClient client= WebClient.create(ROOT_URL_FILE_SERVICE);

        client.type("multipart/form-data");     
        InputStream is= new ByteArrayInputStream(getBytes());       
        List<Attachment> attachments= new ArrayList();
        ContentDisposition cd = new ContentDisposition("attachment;filename=image.jpg");
        Attachment att= new Attachment("File", is, cd);
        Attachment pageNumber= new Attachment("DATA1", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, "1");
        Attachment OutputType= new Attachment("DATA2", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, "2");

        attachments.add(att);
        attachments.add(pageNumber);
        attachments.add(OutputType);
        MultipartBody body= new MultipartBody(attachments);

        Response res=client.post(body);
```

I am unable to get anything (File,DATA1,DATA2) on server side.

What is that i need to modify in above code to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Check your server side cxf configuration is something like below.

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String upload(
        @Multipart(value = "File", type = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) final InputStream fileStream,
        @Multipart(value = "DATA1", type = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) final String fileNumber,
        @Multipart(value = "DATA2", type = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) final String outputType) {
    BufferedImage image;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(fileStream);
        LOG.info("Received Image with dimensions {}x{} ", image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    LOG.info("Received Multipart data1 {} ", fileNumber);
    LOG.info("Received Multipart data2 {} ", outputType);
    return "Recieved all data";
}
```

The tested client file

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/services/kp/upload");
            ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(client);
            config.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
            config.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
            client.type("multipart/form-data");
            InputStream is = FileUtils.openInputStream(new File("vCenter_del.jpg"));
            List<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
            ContentDisposition cd = new ContentDisposition("attachment;filename=image.jpg");
            Attachment att = new Attachment("File", is, cd);
            Attachment pageNumber = new Attachment("DATA1", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, "1");
            Attachment OutputType = new Attachment("DATA2", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, "2");

            attachments.add(att);
            attachments.add(pageNumber);
            attachments.add(OutputType);
            MultipartBody body = new MultipartBody(attachments);

            Response res = client.post(body);

            String data = res.readEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println(data);
        }
```

**NOTE:** In short if there is mismatch in content-id that if file,data1 or content-type, server might not recieve the data in both cases you will get appropriate error such as 400 and 415 respectively.